# Segmentation fault: 11 (C++ File input and output, classes and dynamic arrays)

Tags: c++, string, file-io, dynamic-arrays

I am working on a program that should read a file, take its content as input and write it to a dynamic array. Every time I execute the program to output (printout) the words, that should have been taken as input, I get a "segmentation fault:11". The concept of the program is to read a file that contains a word in english along with its translation in spanish and printout both. The original code is larger but I have only included File I/O and dynamic arrays which are the ones triggering the segfault. Any help on why this is happening and a posible fix is appreciated.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

class diccionario {
public:
    void abrir_file (ifstream& entrada, ofstream& salida);
    diccionario();
    ~diccionario();
    void escribir(ofstream& salida);
    void validar();
private:
    string *espdic;
    string *engdic;
    int size;
};

diccionario::diccionario () : cantidad(0), size(10) {
    string *espdic = new string [size];
    string *engdic = new string [size];
}

diccionario::~diccionario () {

}

void abrir_file (ifstream& entrada, ofstream& salida) {
  entrada.open ("palabras.txt");
  if(entrada.fail())
    {
      cout << "Error abriendo archivo" << endl;
      salida << "Error abriendo archivo" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }

  salida.open ("salida.txt");
  if(salida.fail())
    {
      cout << "Error abriendo archivo" << endl;
      salida << "Error abriendo archivo" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }   
}

int main() {
    int opcion, size;
    ifstream entrada;
    ofstream salida;
    string temp;
    diccionario english;
    string *espdic = new string [size];
    string *engdic = new string [size];

    abrir_file (entrada, salida);

    if(entrada.is_open()) {
        while(entrada >> temp) {
            engdic[size] = temp;
            size++;
        }
    }

    do {
        menu(salida);
        cin >> opcion;
        switch (opcion) {

            case 1:
            english.escribir(salida);
            break;

            case 2:
            cout << "Fin de programa" << endl;
            salida << "Fin de programa" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    } while (opcion != 0);

    salida.close();
    entrada.close();

    return 0;
}
```

input file (palabras.txt):

```
God Dios
Violet Violeta
Ray Rayo
Master Maestro
Power Poder
```

Comment: 1. `diccionario::diccionario()` causes memory leak. 2. In `main()` uninitialized `size` is used to allocate array. 3.  In `main()` `engdic[size]` and further is out-of-range and must not be accessed. 4. `menu()` and `diccionario::escribir()` are used, but aren't defined.

Comment: @MikeCAT #4 is defined, sorry I did not include it in my code but it is defined its just way tooo long. I wanted to keep it short. So it is recommended to initialize `size`, remove the constructor `diccionario` and remove `engdic[size]` on `main()`... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see few problems here.

1. `size` not provided.

In main function. You declared size variable but never gave value to it. Lets say you need to allocate for 25 elements. use as

```
int size=25;
```

2. Access something out of bound.

   engdic[size] = temp;

Assuming, allocation of engdic is for 25 elements, its index starts from 0 and ends with 24 (engdic[0] to engdic[24]), however, in above statement size is uninitialized it may be accessing more that 24, causing segmentation fault.

3. `size` not initialized to zero before `while` loop.

In code below, what is starting and ending value of size? Ideally you should start with 0 and end with maximum capacity (24 here)

> while(entrada >> temp) {
>       engdic[size] = temp;
>       size++; }